# Localize entire stylesheet to one div?

Tags: html, css, laravel

On my laravel app, I'm using a forum package called "chatter".

This forum is injected into my master layout, so it looks like this:

- nav bar
- chatter package
- footer

It's injected into a container called `<div id="chatter">`, and its styles are found in the style sheet `chatter.css`, which is separate from my main sheet.

The problem is, some of the styles in this sheet are conflicting with my nav and footer. Furthermore, some of the styles in my main sheet are affecting the forum (albeit minimally, so I don't mind making the changes manually).

I can't change the markup, but I can edit the styles.

So how could I make it so that all the styles found in `chatter.css` ONLY apply to what's inside of `<div id="chatter">`?

Comment: You could rewrite `chatter.css` to add `#chatter` to the start of each rule, or (if possible) put the chatter package in an IFRAME to isolate it. If neither of those are doable, you might need to just fix the conflicts manually, whether in your markup/CSS or theirs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add #chatter to every style in chatter.css like this

```
#chatter table{...}
#chatter tr{...}
#chatter td{...}
etc.
```

If style is for level above the chatter div then add after like this:

```
html #chatter{..}
body #chatter div{...}
```

Comment: Hm... there's 5000 lines of styles. Is this the only option?

Comment: Other solution is using iFrame.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to namespace your CSS as user Nawed Khan pointed out but there is a much simpler way to do that than changing each of your styles manually.  This method uses less to handle it for you.

Drop this in a file called `chatter.less`.

```
#chatter {
    @import (less) 'chatter.css';  
}
```

Then you need to include it on your page...

```
<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="chatter.less" >
```

Then you need to include `less.js` AFTER you've included your .less file.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/less.js/2.7.2/less.min.js"></script>
```

In your `.less` file you might have to mess with the path to `chatter.css`, I believe it's going to be relative to whatever file you are including the `.less` file on.

Comment: The would rely on client side less... Which is a bit heavy for just that.